# Autowiring not working with @RestController

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven

I need to create a simple REST-service with some fields I want to export from applicatonContext.xml file, but I've got

**Stack-Trace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 's3RestController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.emc.sk.data_mgmt_central.server.S3RestController.path; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=path)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at com.emc.sk.data_mgmt_central.main.Main.main(Main.java:39)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.emc.sk.data_mgmt_central.server.S3RestController.path; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=path)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 16 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=path)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1009)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
... 18 common frames omitted
```

I run application with

**Main class**

```
@ComponentScan("com.emc.sk.data_mgmt_central.server")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);   
    }
}
```

And here is my

**RestController**

```
@RestController
@ContextConfiguration("/FileStorageContext.xml")
public class S3RestController {

@Autowired
private String path;

@RequestMapping("/getBucket")
public Bucket getBucket(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="world") String name) {
    return new Bucket(name);
}   
}
```

My applicationContext is called FileStorageContext and stored in src/main/recourses (I've got a maven project)

**FileStorageContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean name = "path" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="#{ systemProperties['java.io.tmpdir'] }bucketDir" />
</bean>
```

@Autowired works properly in my tests, but here this error occurs. I am new in Spring, maybe this construction is not correct at all. Thanks.

Comment: This usually means that you aren't importing your config properly. This is the sort of thing that would be a lot easier with JavaConfig or even just `@Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put
@ImportResource("classpath:/FileStorageContext.xml") before my Main class, the problem was that this file wasn't seen.

Answer (score 2):

Add `@PropertySource("classpath:/your/properties/path/applicatio.properties")`
to your controller and add `@Value` tag to path instead of `@Autowired`.

```
@Value("${java.io.tmpdir}")
private String path;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line causes your exception:

```
@Autowired
private String path;
```

Autowiring works only on Spring managed beans and `String` should not be considered as one (IMO).

You may use `@Value` annotation if you want to get the value of `path` from your context. Or if you want to use as is, you can try `@Qualifier("path")` annotation along with `@Autowired`.

Comment: IDK why he want to Autowire String also

Comment: Thanks for responce, but using `    @Value("${path}")
    private String path;` didn't solve my problem, I've still got an error. Isn't my bean Spring managed? I autowired path in some of my tests and everything worked fine, though this is not a good decision.

Comment: have you tried `@Value("#{ systemProperties['java.io.tmpdir'] })`. About your tests, it all depends on how you did the testing, however, String is a very special Object and IMO should not be used in this way. Still you may try the `@Qualifier("path")` option